# Mixing vector objects created on heap and on stack

Tags: c++, heap-memory, new-operator

I have a fairly simple question, but cannot wrap my head over it.

Consider I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    B(const int& val) {this->val = val;}
    int val;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    void Set(B& ptb)
    {
        ptBs.push_back(&ptb);
    }
    void Set(const int& val)
    {
        ptBs.push_back(new B(val));
    }
    std::vector<B*> ptBs;
};

int main()
{
    A* ptA = new A();
    ptA->Set(B(10));
    ptA->Set(38);

    for (int i=0; i<ptA->ptBs.size(); i++)
        cout << ptA->ptBs[i]->val << endl;

    delete ptA;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output result is:

```
10
38
```

But I think there is memory leak is going on in `void Set(const int& val)` if I won't call delete with array elements, created by this method.

How can I say, which elements of std::vector have been created on heap so I could free memory in ~A() destructor like this:

```
~A()
{
    for (int i=0; i<ptBs.size(); i++)
        delete ptBs[i];
}
```

And do I have to delete vector elements, created via temporary new operation call at all?

Probably I don't see something very simple here, but I really need this functionality in my application.

PS. 10 and 38 are just a simple example. `Set` function can be called thousands of times with different arguments.

Comment: It's not a deconstructor, it's a destructor.

Comment: You could use `std::pair<bool,B>` to indicate which elements are heap allocated. In destructor you can do `if( ptBs[i].first ) delete ptBs[i].second;`

Comment: Make your life simple - chose one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, this line won't compile:

```
ptA->Set(B(10));
```

This is because `B(10)` is a constructor cast expression which creates a prvalue temporary of type `B`; a prvalue cannot bind to the lvalue reference `B &` parameter to `void A::Set(B& ptb)`.  This is the C++ language protecting you from the consequences of storing a dangling pointer to a temporary value.

It usually makes more sense for `A` to store its `B` items by value:

```
std::vector<B> Bs;
```

Comment: Well the code I provided is fully working and compiling. But yes I decided to store objects in array, rather than pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should decide on whether you give ownership of the object of type `B` to the instance of `A` or not. Mixing both will not lead to anything good. Just imagine documenting this class: `this class may or may not take ownership to the objects it holds.`

Alternative approach that I do not recommend is to create a wrapper to pointers to `B`, that takes a pointer to B and a boolean flag in it constructor and the boolean flag will indicate if the pointer is to an object allocated on the stack or to an object on the heap.